# 'UnknownError',message: 'An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.',orgStatusMessage: 'connection refused with webdriver.io

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am following this guide: http://webdriver.io/guide.html and firefox version I am using 62.0

I followed following steps:

1. I downloaded latest selenium-standalone-server version 3.14.
2. I have downloaded latest gecko driver version 0.22.0 and extracted it in project folder
3. Ran selenium standalone version using command java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./geckodriver selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar
4. Then run the command  npm install webdriverio
5. Created a test file test.js with code

> ```
> var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
> var options = {
>     desiredCapabilities: {
>         browserName: 'firefox'
>     }
> };
>
> webdriverio
>     .remote(options)
>     .init()
>     .url('http://www.google.com')
>     .getTitle().then(function(title) {
>         console.log('Title was: ' + title);
>     })
>     .end()
>     .catch(function(err) {
>         console.log(err);
>     });
> ```

6. node test.js

instead of getting output "Title was: Google"
i get error

```
{ Error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
    at end() - test.js:15:6
  details: undefined,
  message: 'connection refused\nBuild info: version: \'3.4.0\', revision: \'unknown\', time: \'unknown\'\nSystem info: host: \'RITESHs-MacBook-Pro.local\', ip: \'192.168.1.2\', os.name: \'Mac OS X\', os.arch: \'x86_64\', os.version: \'10.13.6\', java.version: \'1.8.0_171\'\nDriver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver\nremote stacktrace: stack backtrace:\n   0:        0x10b43d49e - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h3ab5720c483fe461\n   1:        0x10b43d4dc - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::h096accf58447e0d5\n   2:        0x10b376534 - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::hc0958d01acda7bfc\n   3:        0x10b37d300 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler::create_connection::h59a68c8dfef48e54\n   4:        0x10b35cd3c - _$LT$webdriver..server..Dispatcher$LT$T$C$$u20$U$GT$$GT$::run::h5a26ba0bb4fdb139\n   5:        0x10b3350c5 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h3f868f7a1a12bdcc\n   6:        0x10b33fd2d - std::panicking::try::do_call::hfce1ad2a948c3632\n   7:        0x10b4e9a5c - __rust_maybe_catch_panic\n   8:      0x10b352eb5 - _$LT$F$u20$as$u20$alloc..boxed..FnBox$LT$A$GT$$GT$::call_box::h651dedb755194a8c\n   9:        0x10b4e5c4b - std::sys::imp::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::h48c72bb09587cbc3\n  10:     0x7fff515f0660 - _pthread_body\n  11:     0x7fff515f050c- _pthread_start',
  type: 'RuntimeError',
  seleniumStack:
   { type: 'UnknownError',
     message: 'An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.',
     orgStatusMessage: 'connection refused\nBuild info: version: \'3.4.0\', revision: \'unknown\', time: \'unknown\'\nSystem info: host: \'RITESHs-MacBook-Pro.local\', ip: \'192.168.1.2\', os.name: \'Mac OS X\', os.arch: \'x86_64\', os.version: \'10.13.6\', java.version: \'1.8.0_171\'\nDriver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver\nremote stacktrace: stack backtrace:\n   0:        0x10b43d49e - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h3ab5720c483fe461\n   1:        0x10b43d4dc - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::h096accf58447e0d5\n2:        0x10b376534 - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::hc0958d01acda7bfc\n   3:        0x10b37d300 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler::create_connection::h59a68c8dfef48e54\n   4:        0x10b35cd3c - _$LT$webdriver..server..Dispatcher$LT$T$C$$u20$U$GT$$GT$::run::h5a26ba0bb4fdb139\n   5:        0x10b3350c5 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h3f868f7a1a12bdcc\n   6:        0x10b33fd2d - std::panicking::try::do_call::hfce1ad2a948c3632\n   7:        0x10b4e9a5c - __rust_maybe_catch_panic\n   8:        0x10b352eb5 - _$LT$F$u20$as$u20$alloc..boxed..FnBox$LT$A$GT$$GT$::call_box::h651dedb755194a8c\n   9:        0x10b4e5c4b - std::sys::imp::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::h48c72bb09587cbc3\n  10:     0x7fff515f0660 - _pthread_body\n  11:     0x7fff515f050c - _pthread_start' } }
```

can anyone please guideline how to resolve this error ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is a bit of messup. You have mentioned:

- Downloaded latest **selenium-standalone-server version 3.14**
- Command

  ```
  java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./geckodriver selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar
                              observe the versioning ^^^ info
  ```
- Log messages reflect:

  ```
  Build info: version: \'3.4.0\'
  ```

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.22.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v62.0*** levels.
- Execute your *test*

Comment: sorry for mess.will keep in mind from next time.thanks for help.